# Discord bot listen to commands on specific channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bunch of commands in my discord bot and what I am trying to do is to make the bot listen to some commands ONLY if they come from a specific channel.

Here is an example of a command:

```
@bot.command(name='bitcoin',
                brief="Shows bitcoin price for nerds.")
async def bitcoin(pass_context=True):
    url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json'
    response = requests.get(url)
    value = response.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
    await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='<channel id is inserted here>'), "Bitcoin price is: " + value)
    # await bot.say("Bitcoin price is: " + value)
```

I can give the answer in a specific channel that I want, but I want the bot to only reply if the command is triggered in a specific channel, not everywhere.

I tried a if/else with if message.channel.id = 'id' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a `check` that you can use to decorate your command.  Below we create a `check` using our target channel id, and then decorate our command with that check.

```
def in_channel(channel_id)
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.message.channel.id == channel_id
    return commands.check(predicate)

@bot.command(name='bitcoin', brief="Shows bitcoin price for nerds.")
@is_channel('CHANNEL_ID')
async def bitcoin(pass_context=True):
    url = 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/BTC.json'
    response = requests.get(url)
    value = response.json()['bpi']['USD']['rate']
    await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='<channel id is inserted here>'), "Bitcoin price is: " + value)
    # await bot.say("Bitcoin price is: " + value)
```