# How do I make my discord bot respond when a specific user sends a message in the channel?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I want to have my discord bot respond every time a specific user sends a message in the chat. The code runs but nothing happens when that user sends a message.

This is what I have tried so far:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
        
    if message.author.id == '546474118711869440':
        await message.channel.send('shhhhh')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord bot listen to commands on specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989035/discord-bot-listen-to-commands-on-specific-channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in a string. You have to put the user id as an int, so no quotes.

```
if message.author.id == 546474118711869440:
    await message.channel.send('shhhhh')
```

Comment: thank you ! my bad for a dumb question lol

Comment: @TyStrong It's fine, happens to the best of us